# (Mathematica newbie) How to avoid this error ? Animate with predefined and nested functions

Tags: graphics, function-construction, animation

So im trying to do the Atwood machine for project and I try to do it as simple as possible. I defined a graphical functions for elements and also a function of move equation.

```
Pulley = Graphics[Style[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1], Red]]

LineL[d_] := Graphics[Line[{{-.1, 0}, {-.1, -.5 - d}}]]

LineR[d_] := Graphics[Line[{{.1, 0}, {.1, -.5 + d}}]]

Elevator[x_] := 
 Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[{-0.15, -.7 - x}, {-0.05, -.5 - x}]}]

Mass[x_] := 
 Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0.05, -.55 + x}, {0.15, -.5 + x}]}]
```

> So these are the graphical objects definitions

```
x[t_] := (300 - 100)/(300 + 100) 9.8 t^2/2
```

> And move equation

I checked this setup with **Show** function to see if it works

```
Show[Pulley, LineL[x[0]], LineR[x[0]], Elevator[x[0]], Mass[x[0]]]
```

Until this point everything goes right. The problem occurs when i try to use **Animate** function to make it move.

```
Animate[Pulley, LineL[x[t]], LineR[x[t]], Elevator[x[t]], 
 Mass[x[t]], {t, 0.1, 1}]
```

> Error:"Animate argument LineL[x[t]] does not have the correct form for a 
> variable specification" Repeated for every variable.

I checked the documentation and functions where defined inside the **Animate** so i guess that may be the case for me. So the question is, can I somehow make it work as intendent or should i re-write the program ? Or is there another function i can use ? Please let me know

Comment: Animate takes 2 arguments, a list of graphics and a variable specification. Therefore, you must wrap your graphics command into a list: `{...}`

Answer (score 3):

First, Animate takes 2 arguments, a list of graphics and a variable specification. Therefore, you must wrap your graphics command into a list: {...}.

Then, to get a general coordinate system, you must wrap all the graphics into one single `Graphics`. Otherwise, every item has its own coordinate system.

Then you must adept the time range, otherwise your machine overshoots:

Here is the code:

```
Pulley = {Style[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1], Red]};
LineL[d_] := Line[{{-.1, 0}, {-.1, -.5 - d}}]
LineR[d_] := Line[{{.1, 0}, {.1, -.5 + d}}]
Elevator[x_] := {Green, Rectangle[{-0.15, -.7 - x}, {-0.05, -.5 - x}]}
Mass[x_] := {Blue, Rectangle[{0.05, -.55 + x}, {0.15, -.5 + x}]}
x[t_] := (300 - 100)/(300 + 100) 9.8 t^2/2

Animate[
 Graphics[{
   Pulley, LineL[x[t]], LineR[x[t]], Elevator[x[t]], Mass[x[t]]
   }, PlotRange -> {{-.2, .2}, {-1.2, .2}}, Frame -> True], {t, 
  0.1, .4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response !